# how to set full width and height for email template in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my left.html , [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hqmahjrh/)

I need to set full width for header and footer without change alignment of content.

I tried `width:100%;` , the problem is that, I m using template and it all has `<table>`.

css:

```
body,#bodyTable,#bodyCell{
            height:100% !important;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            width:100% !important;
        }
        table{
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
```

Can anyone help me , how to set?

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add css style like this:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Give the left and right margin as none !important for this class

Comment: How you changed the css?

Comment: How you gave the margin none property?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
  
  <td>test</td>
  <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Add inline style for the table, Because it is email template.